# would have had to have been?

Tags: have

in the following string:

- ... a minuscule proportion of the millions that necessarily would have had to have been slaughtered within the overkill scenario.

what does  "would have had to have been" mean ?

Comment: That's not a sentence.

Comment: Imagine a Ministry of Food & Agriculture official, Mr Brown,  defending the fact that 10 000 cattle have recently been slaughtered to combat a foot-and-mouth epidemic, in 199x. "We _could_ have chosen the overkill option. But we went with the traced-cull option. We would have had to slaughter millions had we chosen the overkill option." // Now imagine a newsreader reporting this: "10 000 cattle have been put down; according to Mr Brown, this is a minuscule proportion of the millions that necessarily would have had to have been slaughtered within the overkill scenario."

Comment: It means exactly the same as I would have meant if I'd written ***...would have been** slaughtered within the overkill scenario* - or even just ***...would be** slaughtered...*, come to that. Who cares whether they were slaughtered ***of necessity*** or not, in such contexts?

Comment: @Ashworth, I may not understand what you mean, could you explain it in a simpler way?